# Which amino acids can be phosphorylated?

Tags: amino-acids

Definitely serine, tyrosine, and threonine. What about aspartate and glutamate? I thought the O- on the carboxylic acid side group could be phosphorylated but am getting mixed responses to this. Any thoughts / any other amino acids I'm missing?

Comment: Also check out the [relevant wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_phosphorylation#Sites). For ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions, you are **required** to show your attempt to answer the question and to use the "homework" tag. (Note that "homework" can apply to questions even if they are not assigned as homework — for example those that are trivial to biology professionals and thus easily answered by searching.) ——— Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: I don’t see why it is suggested that this is a homework question. Most readers will not know the answer, and if there happens to be a resource that has all that information it may not be obvious to the poster. If either of those who have commented are able to provide a comprehensive answer which puts the topic into perspective, they should do so. The question is not posed in a very academic manner, but it can always be improved upon. A mere list is clearly of little interest.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Wikinome page called [Phosphorylation of unusual amino acids](http://kinase.com/wiki/index.php/Phosphorylation_on_unusual_amino_acids) describing phosphorylation of histidine, aspartate, cysteine, lysine, and arginine. Lysine and arginine are apparently phosphorylated on the nitrogens. I was a little surprised to see histidine and aspartate on the list, as histidine kinases seem to come up often in my area of research.

I'm also aware of at least one non-proteinogenic amino acid, creatine, which is [phosphorylated by a dedicated creatine kinase](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4898252/). It functions as a sort of phosphate shuttle for rapid regeneration of cellular ATP from ADP in situations of high metabolic demand.

References:

Phosphorylation on unusual amino acids. (http://kinase.com/wiki/index.php/Phosphorylation_on_unusual_amino_acids)

PubMed Abstracts: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=18558627%2C10772951%2C10698688%2C1654322%2C9553104%2C8577821%2C19498169%5Buid%5D

Guimarães-Ferreira L. Role of the phosphocreatine system on energetic homeostasis in skeletal and cardiac muscles. Einstein (Sao Paulo). 2014;12(1):126-131. doi:10.1590/s1679-45082014rb2741